# Get list of all Grandchild Pages

Tags: wp-query, pages, child-pages

I have the following page hierarchy, all of which are under a top page (TOP) with ID = 1:

- mid1

  - gc1
  - gc2
- mid2

  - gc3
  - gc4

I would like to make submit `WP_Query` query that will return random pages that are grandchildren of TOP - in this example, I want to randomly select from gc1, gc2, gc3 and gc4, but exclude mid1 and mid2. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My current idea is:

1. Use `get_pages` to get all of the descendants of TOP and put the IDs in an array `arrayAll`.
2. Then run `get_pages` again with `parent=1` to get just the direct children of TOP. Put these in array `arrayChildren`.
3. Run in php `arrayGrandchildren = array_diff(arrayAll, arrayChildren)` to get a list of all pages from the first array (which contains all descendants of TOP) that do not include the direct children.
4. In `WP_Query`, set '`post_in=arrayGrandchildren&order=rand`' to get random posts from the list of grandchildren.